# issue mounting new logical volume rhel

Tags: linux, mount, logical-drive

I am having an issue mounting a logical drive to a folder on a RHEL VM.  Below are the steps I took:

```
1. added a new drive to my computer (allocated more space to the VM)
2. created partition, sdb1, using 'fdisk /dev/sdb' and set to "linux LVM" (8e)
3. formatted sdb1 to ext3 with following cmd: mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
4. added sdb1 to volume: vgextend /dev/sdb1
5. Created Logical volume: lvcreate -L 10G VolGroup00
6. Mounted: mount -t ext3 /dev/VolGroup00/lvol0 /test
```

the mount command gave me the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/VolGroup00/lvol0,
   missing codepage or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

When I run `dmesg | tail` I get:

```
VFS: Can't find ext3 filesystem on dev dm-2.
```

Is there something I did wrong?  I dont know why it cant find the ext3 filesystem because I definitely created it.  I have redone this twice now.

Comment: You seem to have forgot `mke2fs -j /dev/VolGroup00/lvol0`.

Comment: thank you!  That worked.  One question:  What is the difference between mke2fs and mkfs.ext3? when calling mkfs.ext3 it did not work.  When calling mke2fs as you suggested, it worked.  I did not specify the -j option on my mkfs.ext3 command because the man page says its already implied for mkfs.ext3

Comment: `mkfs.ext3` and `mke2fs -j` produce identical results, EXT3 is basically EXT2 with journaling and `-j` just toggles the journaling on.

Comment: yeah thats what I thought!  I completely missed your point the first time around.  I read your comment as `mke2fs -j /dev/sdb1` instead of `mke2fs -j /dev/VolGroup00/lvol0`.  I just copied and pasted your code and ran it and still missed that I needed to create the file system on the LV instead of the PV.  I was racking my head trying to figure out the difference between what you suggested and what I did.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sami Laine pointed out, I had created the filesystem on the physical volume, but not the logical volume.  Here is the command I forgot:

```
mke2fs -j /dev/VolGroup00/lvol0
```